# How do I install ruby-opengl on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, opengl, installation, rake

I have a one-click ruby installation on my windows7 x32 os. When trying to install ruby-opengl following the project's instructions [link](http://ruby-opengl.rubyforge.org/) i get the following errors regardless if i install from rubygems or do the manual build:

"[dir]/lib/rake/gempackagetask is deprecated. Use rubygems/package_task instead"

"[dir]/lib/mkrf/rakehelper.rb:44: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config."

I have tried several solutions like forcing to install on mswin platform (--platform=mswin32) but nothing works.

Comment: Hi there, you seem pretty new to Stack Overflow, so I thought I should let you know why you're downvoted a bit here. Mostly we like the question-answer pattern here. So, while what you've got is definitely very useful - a better way to have done it, would be to have phrase your main post in question form - eg to lay out the issue you encountered... then you'd put your solution as an "answer" to your own question (yes, that's allowed - you can even "accept" the answer). Then it would fit with the S/O Best Practice. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, i would have done it that way but suddenly felt really awkward to answer my own question. However i appreciate this website very much, its very well structured and easy to read, so i will be happy to stick to question-answer in the future.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working method to install ruby-opengl on windows platform can be found here: [Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyinstaller/vMR5mQVA_88)

I thought it may help since i spent more than a day finding a thread with the solution to the problem and the fix is actually really not obvious.

The fix posted in the thread can be summarized as follows:

[...

So for now installing ruby-opengl is this (in short):

- Install the DevKit.
- Install the mkrf gem if not installed, and then apply the mingw patch to it.
- Download the ruby-opengl, using gem fetch for instance, unpack it, modify one c file and three mkrf_conf.rb
- Build the gem from the unpacked source. There is a bug in gem build, it needs adding a require yaml (to rubygems.rb for instance) for the build to succeed
- Add glut.h and glut32.dll in the right place, I put it in DevKit/mingw
- Finally gem install the rebuilt gem

...]

Comment: Hi, if the link dies i dont think the answer would be useful either, the author of the fix had to change the original gem files in order to make it work, also did changes in the mkrf. He has uploaded the fixed files to that thread

Comment: Right... i hope its better now (though i wouldn't be able to install it without the download files i understand some people might be able to do it much easier following these hints in case the link is gone). Thank you.